# How do you properly include a resource folder in a JAR artifact in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, jar

I have a project that reads graphics and sound effects from a folder labeled res. This folder is at the same directory level as the src folder. I have res marked as Resources Root.

I configured my artifact to include res as a Content Directory by way of 
Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Add (Alt + Insert) -> JAR

Then, in the output layout tab, I pressed the Add dropdown box -> Directory Content -> res

When I run the project in Intellij, it finds the resources just fine. Here is a code snippet showing how I access the resources:

```
public static final Sfx VOID_SOUND = new Sfx(TinySound.loadSound(new File("res/audio/sfx/void_sound.wav")));
```

However, when I build the standalone artifact, then run the jar, it looks for the resource by prepending the parent directory of my machine to the file path, all the way to root. Here is how the terminal output looks:

```
/home/user/Demo/res/audio/sfx/void_sound.wav (No such file or directory)
Error getting resource stream!
```

Is there a way to configure the artifact build to where it looks in the proper place? I want the resources included inside the jar file so it acts as a standalone jar with no external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Linux so please take this with a grain of salt. But to me, it looks like its trying to access the file from where it doesn't have permission.  Have you tried moving the file or directory to a shared location where any user can access it?

Comment: It definitely has permissions in that directory because it's in the home directory of my user account. My account is the only other account other than root on this machine so this is the closest to a shared location as it gets. The only way it could not have permissions is if it was in a directory marked with root only permissions.

Answer (score 0):

All the files from [`resource/source` folders](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-root.html#root_types) inside your module's [**Content root**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-root.html#d99012e23) are included into artifact on [artifact build](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html#build_artifacts). You can explore the artifact content produced (the artifact is placed into a directory specified in **Output directory** field in Artifct's [Generat Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/general-settings-name-type-etc.html)) yourself.

Make sure you are specifying the correct directory for the file. E.g. if the `res` folder is marked as the module's `resource root` the file path name in the artifact will start from the sub-folder inside the `res` directory, that is `audio/sfx/void_sound.wav`.

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand why it doesn't work. It's because resources included within the JAR artifact must be included in the classpath and are accessible using `getResource()`. Resources outside the classpath must be accessed using a filepath. If you use a relative path, it will resolve to where the pwd where the JAR is launched form, not to inside the JAR, hence the reason it resolves back to root. The solution is to put the resources in the classpath and access them using `getClass().getResource()` or `getClass().getLoader().getResource()`.